# Strange message appearing when using Wolfram Alpha in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I have Mathematica 9.0.1.0 and I've recently noticed that whenever I press the equals sign and type something like Sech[x]^2, I get the message:

[image]

I then tried other search queries, such as p^2, Hamiltonian, and 40 degrees 39'44''. I keep getting the same message, though. What's strange is that, regardless of the search query, Mathematica still correctly interprets the input. Does anyone know why this message appears? I only started seeing it a week or two ago.

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend that you restart Mathematica and see if this behavior persists.

Comment: I tried restarting Mathematica as well as restarting my computer, but the only difference I saw was that the message appeared twice rather than once when I typed Sech[x]^2.

Comment: As a nuclear last resort option you can use `Off[]` to hide the message.

Comment: Do you get the same error with `WolframAlpha["Sech[x]^2","MathematicaResult"]`?  I believe this is equivalent to using the equals sign at the beginning of an input cell.

Comment: @bobthechemist Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue should now be resolved.  If it isn't, please try restarting Mathematica, and try your input again.

If this still fails, then please post the output of:

`PacletInformation["WolframAlphaClient"]`

Comment: Perfect! This solves the problem. Do you know if it was a bug in the system?

Comment: There was a small conflict in an update that went out that was causing V8 and V9 clients to issue these messages with certain preference settings enabled.  This error shouldn't have caused any functional issues, just unnecessary messages, but was fixed with an update.